# CSS edit not work

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress website. I usually make changes in CSS file of theme without any problem but there is file in which CSS changes do not appear. But they do appear while inspecting element.

But while inspecting it shows some digits after the file name. The file name is theme.css, but inspector show me the file name: theme.css?ver=15350008013:1

[image: file name shown in inspector]

CSS is compacted and all codes are in one line.

[image: CSS file]

Any change in the CSS file not happen but in the inspector shown. Why CSS editing not working?

Comment: have you included theme.css two times? try deleting all the code from theme.css and add body{display:none;} to check any code problem in theme.css, sometimes if you miss any semicolon or add anextra semicolon in your css file, your css will no reflect

Comment: This might be issue of caching. This could be cache version of css. Try to flush it out using CTRL + F5 or CTRL + R.

Comment: Are you using a minify or caching plugin? You may need to purge those.

Comment: dear @charankumar. I deleted all of codes in the css file and paste body{display:none;} in the file but site still work correctly. I do not have any idea why it is still working

Comment: dear @nir. I have tried CTRL+F5 but this not works too.

Comment: dear @David.J. I do not have any caching plugin. What plugin do you suggest?

Comment: can you post the link of your site

Comment: W3 Cache plugin will be ideal plugin to purge cache

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly standard of most caching plugins for Wordpress.

```
theme.css?ver=15350008013:1
```

Is requesting a cached version of the file.

The CSS being all in one line is a minified version of the file. This is done to reduce the load on the server by making the file smaller.

Suggestions:

1. Look through your theme settings to see if there is any mention
   of caching.
2. Look through your plugins and see if there is any
       mention of caching.

Once found, clear / flush the cache.

Your changes should now be loaded by the server.

Generally what happens when you clear out the cache is that your plugin / theme will be unable to find a cached version and will minifiy and generate you a new version based off the original and you will see a new number at the end of the request string to tell the browser that the version it has downloaded previously is old and that it needs the new one.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I cannot find any cache part in my theme setting. What plugin for caching you suggest to install?